Spring's reactive WebClient does not fetch response body but Postman does
I have simple spring-boot 3.3 web-flux server which runs on Netty with method:
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<DataEntity> getData(@PathVariable("id") String extId) {
        return dataRepository.findByExtId(extId);
    }

definition of repository:
public interface DataRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<DataEntity, String> {
    Mono<DataEntity> findByExtId(String extId);
}

repository is backed by reactive MySQL driver:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.asyncer</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>

and simple web client:
webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();
Mono<DataDto> mono = webClient.get()
                .uri("/api/{id}", id)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(DataDto.class);

DataDto dto = mono.block();

The problem is client never gets response body.
I can see in the logs that the server does send response with body and client does receive response, but body is always null
But when i perform the same request with Postman i do get response body with expected json data.
Moreover curl does not get body as well
curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/0011
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/0011 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.1
> Accept: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 0


but wget does
wget http://localhost:8080/api/0011
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 231
Довжина: 231 [application/json]

 {"id":1,"extId":"001","status":"NEW"} 
100%[=============================>]     231  --.-KB/s    за 0s

Any manipulations with http headers adding/removing keep-alive, Accept, etc din't bring any result.
One more fact if i replace call to repository with simple Mono.just(data) body is retrieved in all cases
Is there reasonable explanation what is going on here?
I could admit that reactive db access is somewhat "raw" technology with not expected behaviour, but why Postman and wget get data and others don't
Similar problem was described and answered here
Reactive WebClient not emitting a response
but it was 7 years ago and api has changed (and i hope improved) since then

Are you sure you make exactly same request in both cases? First one says it makes a call to /api/card/card_0011, but the second is /api/0011.

absolutely. just copied code from two different versions

I guess you have to find the difference in the requests, that would tell why it behaves differently

I feel silly but the issue with webClient was caused by improper request logger i was playing with and forgot about. It read body but ever printed and next call to getBody returned null cause we have already read it.
Even more silly case is with curl. I gave wrong object id "0011" instead of "001". Taking into account that the server is not real one but poc i've sketched in 5 min it always returned 200 despite object was not found.
The only good outcome of this is once again proved concept: when you see "miracles" like this put laptop aside and take a walk/drink/nap

I had the same problem.
Looks like you have to use .toBodilessEntity() in case there is not expected body.
        webClient.put()
            .uri("/process-data/{symbolId}", 24)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(Void.class)
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .subscribe(response -> {
                LOGGER.info("Success {}", response);
                future.complete(10L);
            }, t -> {
                LOGGER.info("Failure ", t);
                future.complete(-1L);
            });

